# How can I make a Python script that can download certain bookmarked links from multiple local HTML files generated by Chrome?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, google-chrome, download

I am trying to make a Python code on opening and downloading bookmarked links via multiple HTML files that are locally saved. The links that I specifically want to download are .mp4 links while having all the other non-mp4 links filtered out and ignored.

This is the code that I attempted to try out but I am unable to get it to work.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to download .mp4 files
def download_mp4(url, directory):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        filename = os.path.join(directory, url.split("/")[-1])
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f"Downloaded: {url}")

# Main function to HTML and download .mp4 files
def download_mp4_from_html(html_file, output_directory):
    with open(html_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        html_content = f.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a')

    for link in links:
        url = link.get('href')
        if url and url.endswith('.mp4'):
            download_mp4(url, output_directory)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_directory = "downloads/test"

    if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
        os.makedirs(output_directory)

    download_mp4_from_html(html_file_path, output_directory)
```